# How to make a tab bar application from scratch

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, ios, uitabbar

How do you make a tab bar application from scratch, using Interface Builder? Is there a tutorial that shows how to do this?

So far I've figured out that you need to start with a Windows-based application. Then do you open MainWindow.xib and add the tab bar controller there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add a TabBarController from the Library. Then you have to link it to the window's RootViewController, and you're set.

Comment: Is the File's Owner of MainWindow.xib the root view controller? I can't make a connection to it. The only connection it has is delegate.

Comment: In your MainWindow.xib, you have a 'Window' item, of type UIWindow. This item has a 'rootViewController' outlet.